# How to tap on the three dot menu (more options) in the actionbar on Android using Detox?

Tags: detox

How to tap on the three dot menu (more options) in the actionbar on Android using Detox?
[image]

Comment: Give it `testID` and call the `tap()` event.

Comment: The three dot menu automatically appears when an ActionItem position is set to pop in NativeScript. Therefore, I don't know where to set a testID for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this SO answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736139/3970346

Since this is a NativeScript app the steps are,

Create a `ids.xml` file under app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values folder,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="overflowActionButton"/>
</resources>
```

Then in the styles.xml in the same directory add,

```
<style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:id">@id/overflowActionButton</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">"overflowActionButton"</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Finally set the style on the AppThemeBase like this,

```
<!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
        
        <!-- the line below -->
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

After this you can tap on the overflow menu in Detox like this,

```
await element(by.label('overflowActionButton')).tap();
```

Thanks to @Leri Gogsadze for pointing me in the right direction